# String functions SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, string

I have the below string stored in a variable:

```
11608,613,12,12643,12644,12656
```

I want to extract each value before the comma and perform a set of actions.

How to extract each value from the string using SPD 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 6):

This requires a couple of string actions.

1. Find the index of "," in a string
2. copy the string from index 0 to the index position of ","
3. loop until you find the ","

See below working sample. You need to replace ";" with "," in your case

[image]

Comment: I dont see "Copy from" action in my SPD 2013 workflow.

Comment: The action is "Extract Substring of string from Index of length"

Comment: I confirm this works. Just to note, additional action is required before loop to set WF variable pendingStepsExist to Yes. After this modification WF worked as charm.

Comment: this is awesome!  works perfectly to parse an array of id's. so simple too. i've been looking for something like this for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

[Plumsail Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) contains free strings actions, so you can use [Split String](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/actions/String%20processing%20workflow%20actions.html#split-string) action to do this, see an example below: 
[image: SharePoint Workflow Designer Split string]

PS: I want to notice that this is paid product and I'm one of the developers, but you can use [String Processing set](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/actions/String%20processing%20workflow%20actions.html) for free.

Answer (score 0):

I stored 11608,613,12,12643,12644,12656 in a workflow string variable and updated it to a hidden text column in the list.

Then using 2 SharePoint calculated columns, i took each value before the first comma.Then using workflow loop, I updated Calc Column 2 value into the hidden text column till the calc column 2 became empty.

Calc Column 1 formula -

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT([HiddenTextColumn],INT(FIND(",",[HiddenTextColumn])-1))),[HiddenTextColumn],LEFT([HiddenTextColumn],INT(FIND(",",[HiddenTextColumn])-1)))
```

Calc column 2 formula -

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT([HiddenTextColumn],LEN([HiddenTextColumn])-INT(FIND(",",[HiddenTextColumn])))),"HiddenTextColumn",RIGHT([HiddenTextColumn],LEN([HiddenTextColumn])-INT(FIND(",",[HiddenTextColumn]))))
```